# Extract first two digits for each number in the list in R data table

Tags: r, list, datatable, strsplit

I have a column in a data table that consists of codes for purchases. If in my contract (each contract = new row)there is one purchase then the code number is just one character type variable (for instance, 11.25.64). But if my contract has several purchases then the codes are stored in a list. It looks something like this

```
dt n  codes
   1  11.25.64
   2  c('11.25.16', '25.84.78', '78.26.99')
   3  81.62.16
   4  c('16.25.16', '99.84.78', '28.26.99')
```

For the purpose of classifying I want to extract only the first two digits of each of the codes. So, I want to create a new column and to get something like this:

```
 dt n  classification_codes
    1  11
    2  c('11', '25', '78')
    3  81
    4  c('16', '99', '28')
```

I tried executing the following code

```
dt$classification_codes<- substr(dt$codes, start = 1, stop = 2)
```

Yet, it just works for the rows where I have one code, but for the rows with the list variables, it gives 'c('

```
dt n  classification_codes
    1  11
    2  c(
    3  81
    4  c(
```

Then I tried to use a different approach and do something like this

```
dt$classification_codes <- lapply(str_split(dt$codes, " "), substr, 1, 3)
```

But I get the following output. This seems closer to what I want, but still, it is not it. It is as if the first variable in the list isn't readable when I execute the code

```
 dt n  classification_codes
    1  11
    2  c("c(", "\"25","\"78")
    3  81
    4  c("c(", "\"99", "\"28")
```

Comment: What is the difference between 'one purchase' and 'several purchase' IDs? Is it that one purchase IDs always start with 11? It would really help if you include a sample data set and show what the expected output should be. See [reprex] for helpful guidance.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! I provided some sample input data and some expected output

Comment: Do you mind providing a `dput()` of your sample data (or even just the first four rows that you reproduced above)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach you could try with library `stringr`:

```r
a <- c('11.25.16', '25.84.78', '78.26.99')

str_split(a, "\\.")
```

This gives you a list

```r
> str_split(a, "\\.")
[[1]]
[1] "11" "25" "16"

[[2]]
[1] "25" "84" "78"

[[3]]
[1] "78" "26" "99"
```

I tried to solve your problem based on the new information given, so I wrote an ugly function for you:

```r
extractor <- function(string) {
  tmp <- vector()
  if (grepl("^(c[[:punct:]]{2}\\d\\d\\.\\d\\d\\.\\d\\d)", string)) {
    tmp <- string %>% 
          str_extract("^(c[[:punct:]]{2}\\d\\d\\.\\d\\d\\.\\d\\d)") %>%
          str_extract("\\d\\d\\.\\d\\d\\.\\d\\d") %>%
          str_split("\\.")
    tmp <-  paste0("c('", tmp[[1]][1],"', '", tmp[[1]][2], "', '", tmp[[1]][3],"')")
  } else {
    tmp <- string %>%
      str_extract("^(\\d\\d)")
  }
  return(tmp)
}
```

I suppose you have to use

```r
df$new_line <- df$codes %>% lapply(extractor) %>% unlist
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting it, I tried doing it this way by using code `dt$classification_codes <- lapply(str_split(dt$codes, "\\."))` . But I get a mistake: Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default

Comment: with `lapply()` your code should look like this: `lapply(a, str_split, "\\.")`. But just remove `lapply` should give you your desired result.

Comment: Thank you! It actually almost solves the problem! I just now need to figure out how to get only the first character of the split code. But I guess I will be able to do it after some time of thinking

Comment: Added some code. Perhaps it now solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you! Your previous suggestion really helped to solve the issue that I have been struggling with. This function, however, doesn't work. I was suggested to use  `dt$col2 <- sapply(dt$col1,function(x){sapply(x,'[',1)})` on the output that I get from using your code. And this way it works